# How to present geographical and other data on the web

Tags: presentation, gis

I've got a table that I'd like to present. However, a lot the information in it is only useful in aggregated or visual form.
For example, the country column it itself is boring, but a aggregating all the entries of a country would be really useful. Coordinates are in there as well, so any solution should be able to present stuff on a map.

Note that the solution can be non-web, but I'd really prefer a web application everyone can access. What I've found so far is just the Google Maps API, but that's not very good at showing non-geographical information, is it?

Note that the table has a lot of dimensions, often nominal or ordinal (i.e. no numbers), so visual and plotting-focussed libraries are not that good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT: maybe that would help you, in absence of other answers

Today, this article popped into my RSS reader: [Patterns of Destruction?: Visualizing Earthquake Data w/Tableau](http://redmonk.com/sogrady/2010/01/15/earthquake-data/).

The author uses [Tableau](http://www.tableausoftware.com/) to visualize his data and mentions also [Data Applied](http://www.data-applied.com/)  and [GoodData](http://www.gooddata.com/).

---

Combine the Google Maps API with something like the [Javascript Visualization Toolkit](http://thejit.org/)?

There are may libraries out there that might do the trick as well:

- [Raphael](http://raphaeljs.com/)
- [Axis](http://www.axiis.org)
- ...

Comment: JavaScript InfoVis Toolkit looks great for graphs and similar data. Unfortunately, my data is better expressed in a table (or sometimes bar graphs) since it is high-dimensional. Raphael and axis are similarily great for visual stuff, but not applicable in my case. I extended the question to say that.

Comment: In that case, might I recommend the `<table>` tag?

Comment: @jcd Exactly what I'm looking for, but I need additional functionaly like sorting, grouping, and a map/graph interface. The table is about 1000x20, so I can't present it in raw form.